# QTableView based on QSqlTableModel editing new record in place doesn’t save edits in PyQt

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

The form where I have a QTableView has a button to add a new record.  The record appears but any data I type in is not saved.  In fact, once I add a record, no edits to the tableview are saved.  I can edit in place as long as I do not add a new record.  The underlying database is Postgresql.

The question is, how do I add a new record which can be edited immediately?  What am I missing in the code below?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from phones import *

app=QApplication(sys.argv)

QTableView
QSqlTableModel

class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.cont_id = '9'
        self.populate_phones()
        self.ui.new_phone.clicked.connect(self.add_phone)

    def populate_phones(self):
        self.phone_model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.phone_model.setTable("contact_phones")
        self.phone_model.setFilter("contact_id='{0}'".format(self.cont_id))
        self.phone_model.select()

        self.phone_view = self.ui.phone_view
        self.phone_view.setModel(self.phone_model)  
        self.phone_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        
    def add_phone(self):
        self.phone_model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        row = self.phone_model.rowCount()
        record = self.phone_model.record()
        record.setGenerated('id', False)            #primary key
        record.setValue('contact_id', self.cont_id) #foreign key
        self.phone_model.insertRecord(row, record)
        submit = self.phone_model.submitAll()
        #self.phone_model.select()
        phone_index_edit = QModelIndex(self.phone_model.index(row, self.phone_model.fieldIndex('phone_number'))) 
        self.ui.phone_view.edit(phone_index_edit)
        
if __name__=="__main__":

    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName(server)
    db.setDatabaseName(database)
    db.setUserName(user)
    db.setPassword(pword)
    myapp = Main()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the edit strategy to `OnManualSubmit`:

> All changes will be cached in the model until either submitAll() or revertAll() is called.

Once you start editing by calling `edit()` no change will be saved, but only cached. If you close the widget without calling `submitAll()` before, those changes will be lost; this also happens when you try to add a new field, because `insertRecord` will submit only the changes for the inserted record while discarding previous cached changes.

You can just leave the default `OnRowChange` edit strategy, or use `OnFieldChange`.

Further notes about your code:

- the creation of the `QApplication` instance should happen within the `if __name__` block (and those `QTableView` and `QSqlTableModel` lines at the beginning shouldn't be there, as they do nothing);
- you are calling the `__init__` of QWidget, but `Main` is a subclass of QMainWindow; you should either use `QMainWindow.__init__(self)` or subclass from QWidget;
- since you won't be using the `OnManualSubmit` strategy, there is no need to submit after `insertRecord`;
- the creation of a new instance of QModelIndex is unnecessary, since `model.index()` already returns a QModelIndex;

Comment: I have updated my code with your suggestions.  Some of the sloppiness was bad cutting and pasting but your suggestions were really helpful.  I have edited my code.

Comment: If the proposed answer doesn't fix your problem completely then use comments to specify what is happening and what's the expected behavior. **Never** make edits to your questions if those edits are based on answers: it makes both the question and the answers confusing.